# How to change formatting of biblatex in nature style

Tags: biblatex

I would like to change the nature style in biblatex. I tried to use "\DeclareFieldFormat" but it doesn't work.

This is my sample code.

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8,refsegment=chapter,style=nature,firstinits=true,isbn=false,doi=false,url=false,sorting=none,clearlang=true,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]{volume,journal}{#1\isdot}
```

This is a result.
[image: This is a nature style]

It should be a regular style.

How can I change to a regular style for the journal field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things

1. The first mandatory argument of `\DeclareFieldFormat` is not a list. It must be a single field name (or artificial format name). To change the format of multiple fields you need separate `\DeclareFieldFormat` invocations.
2. Internally the title of a journal is called `journaltitle` in `biblatex` and not just `journal`. `journal` is only supported as a legacy alias in the `.bib` input.

Taking these two points into account we can come up with

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=nature,
  sorting=none,
  giveninits=true,
  isbn=false,doi=false,url=false,
  natbib=true
]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{#1\isdot}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson, E. & Ryde, U. Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments. Journal of Computational Chemistry 19, 377–395 (1998).]

Note that I only changed the `volume` format for the types `@article` and `@periodical` (and not for all `@in...` types) to ensure a more consistent output between `@inbook` and `@book`.

Comment: Thank you. It's work.